# I am not able to access SSH for my linux instance

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, google-cloud-platform, rdp, google-compute-engine

I newbie to Google Cloud and Linux. I have created VM linux instance on Google Cloud. Then by using SSH i created Graphical Interface and then i accessed my Linux Graphical Interface using Server Ip using my local windows RDP. After installing few application that i need to upload my project on server i closed my RDP and server.

And here i was facing issue to Transfer my local to remote using SCP from local MACOS which gives me some public-key error

And Now when i tried to open my SSH I am getting following error [here](http://prnt.sc/rfbmp5)

I am also not able to access my RDP which gives me following error [here](https://prnt.sc/rf9exy)

Please let me know if there is anything that i am missing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This error message is a little generic because even if you have this port opened by GCP firewall rules, this could be down, blocked or unresponsive at OS level. Please try [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#debug_with_serial_console) troubleshooting guide, specially nmap and interacting with the serial console. Other of the root causes is your machine has run out of memory or disk space, this could stok the kernel and not permit any kind of process or task like allowing new connections and credential pulls from the outside; to verify this you can look to the [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) logs and look for "Out of memory", "no space left" or "Killing child process" messages. For memory issues you will have to change the [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance) and if there is no space left in the disk you will need to [resize your disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd).